# Using Case statement with multiple when in Teradata

Tags: case, teradata

Suppose I have a data table with the following fields:

CUSTOMER: either A or B

DAY: either Monday or Tuesday

PAID: either Y or N

The total number of rows being four, let's say the data table is this:

```
CUSTOMER   DAY     PAID
A        Monday     Y
A        Tuesday    N
B        Monday     Y
B        Tuesday    N
```

How do I create a SQL query on Teradata SQL Assistant, that will show the number of people who were Y on Monday and N on Tuesday? (or any of these combinations) I tried to use the query below, but cannot seem to figure out the logic. Your help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT DAY, 

COUNT(CASE PAID WHEN 'Y' THEN CUSTOMER ELSE 0 END) AS PAID_CUSTOMERS,

COUNT(CASE WHEN PAID = 'Y' AND DAY = 'Monday' AND DAY = 'Tuesday' AND PAID = 'N' THEN CUSTOMER ELSE 0 END)  AS CUSTOMERS_YM_NT

FROM T1

GROUP BY 1

ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks for making the table and query look nicer. Didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Woulld you expect `AND DAY = 'Monday' AND DAY = 'Tuesday'` to ever be true?  You need a separate case statement for tuesday, then you can compare the two.

Comment: Can you show what the result of your query would be, based on your four row table?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm a novice when it comes to programming. @Andrew, I would want to find out the number of customers who are X on Monday and Y on Tuesday, with X and Y being anything. For example, I want to find out how many customers paid on both days. (Y for both Monday and Tuesday) Or, I might want to find out how many customers paid on neither day. (N for both Monday and Tuesday) Or, anything in between. (Paid only on Monday, Paid only on Tuesday, etc) The key is, I want to find out the number of cases where both parameters (Monday and Tuesday) are specified as something.

Comment: @Nick, the result might look like this: The result table has two columns, Scenario and Number. Scenario = Paid on both days, Number = 0. Scenario = Paid on neither day, Number = 0. Scenario = Paid only on Monday, Number = 2. Scenario = Paid only on Tuesday, Number = 0. It would be 4 rows and 2 columns (excluding headers)

Answer (score 0):

So, break each day down into a separate case statement:

```
    case when DAY = 'Monday' and PAID = 'NO' then 'NO' else 'YES' end as Monday,
    case when DAY = 'Tuesday' and PAID = 'NO' then 'NO' else 'YES end as Tuesday,
etc
```

Then, you can wrap that with another select and apply whatever criteria you want:

```
select 
<whatever columns>
from
(select
    case when DAY = 'Monday' and PAID = 'NO' then 'NO' else 'YES' end as Monday,
    case when DAY = 'Tuesday' and PAID = 'NO' then 'NO' else 'YES end as Tuesday,
    ...
) t
where Monday 'YES'
and Tuesday = 'YES'
```